# Will auto-discovery of neighbors be implemented for full nodes?

Tags: iri-node, iota-network, neighbors

The most difficult part of setting up a full node is finding neighbors. Will some sort of discovery mechanism be implemented? If so, when? If not, I’m curious why that would be by design.

Answer (score 4):

"Nelson" is a wrapper which facilitates this for IRI. It is made by the carriota.com team. Some reference information so far on it (some people are already using Nelson). There are two blog posts on Medium about CarrIOTA Nelson:

- [CarrIOTA Nelson: Automatic peer discovery for IOTA](https://medium.com/deviota/carriota-nelson-automatic-peer-discovery-for-iota-bdca9b8b8750)
- [CarrIOTA Nelson in a nutshell](https://medium.com/deviota/carriota-nelson-in-a-nutshell-1ee5317d8f19)

It looks like it can be installed via npm
(https://npmjs.com/package/nelson.cli).